# How to mock local variable in a static method of a private java class?

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I am writing unit test for a static method 'updateStatusOfModel' in class 'Util' whose constructor is private.

This static method instantiates a local variable dbManager as follows:

ActivationDBManager dbManager = new ActivationDBManager();

This dbManager is used to call its method which I have to mock.

I have mocked this as follows but somehow, it is not working. Unit test is not picking the mock object for ActivationDBManager.

Any help is appreciated.

```java
@Test 
@PrepareForTest(Util.class) 
void updateStatusModel() throws Exception {     
ActivationDBManager mockdbManager = Mockito.mock(ActivationDBManager.class); 
   PowerMockito.whenNew(ActivationDBManager.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockdbManager);    

PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mockdbManager).updateDBStatus(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());  

Util.updateStatus("", "", "", "");
}
```

Util.updateStatus is a static method.

Comment: but somehow, it is not working -> do you get errors?

Comment: no errors, but the control goes into the actual class method ActivationDBManager. updateDBStatus()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `ActivationDBManager` to `@PrepareForTest`, because you are manipulating its bytecode (using `whenNew`).

Comment: Are you using JUnit5? It looks like it's not so easy to get JUnit 5 and PowerMockito working nicely together. For this reason we use JUnit4 (via the junit5 vintage engine) for tests with PowerMockito, at least up to now that runs without problems.

Comment: You are right. Its working fine with junit4. Thank you so much :)